B2B - SFRA - add JS to frontend using hooks
I'm a beginner in SFRA.
I'm building a cartridge, it is clear to me how to add JS files to the template assets BUT, I want to add some JS scripts WITHOUT overriding one of the basic templates, for better compatibility.
I want to add my JS to the HEAD tag.
Now... as I'm using custom controllers in my JS Ajax calls, I need to pass the URLs somehow.
So, my idea was to leverage this hook
${dw.system.HookMgr.callHook('app.template.htmlHead', 'htmlHead', pdict) || ''}

in templates/default/common/htmlHead.isml
doing something like this into scripts/hooks/app/template.js
'use strict';

var URLUtils = require('dw/web/URLUtils');
var ISML = require('dw/template/ISML');

function htmlHead(pdict) {
  var customControllerPaths = {
    endpointA: URLUtils.https('Myapi-EndpointA').toString(),
    endpointB: URLUtils.https('Myapi-EndpointB').toString(),
    endpointC: URLUtils.https('Myapi-EndpointC').toString()
  };
  var customData = {
    custom: 'data'
  };
  var scriptUrls = {
    scriptOne: URLUtils.staticURL('/js/one.js').toString(),
    scriptTwo: URLUtils.staticURL('/js/two.js').toString()
  };

  // Create a new object to hold the data
  var newPdict = Object.assign({}, pdict, {
    mycustom: {
      customControllerPaths: customControllerPaths,
      customData: customData,
      scriptUrls: scriptUrls
    }
  });

  var params = newPdict

  // Render the template and capture the output
  return ISML.renderTemplate('custom/headExtension', params);
}

exports.htmlHead = htmlHead;

my template is in
templates/default/custom/headExtension.isml

and it is something like this
<iscomment>
    Custom Head Content Start
</iscomment>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_custom_var= "${pdict.mycustom.customData.custom}";
    var my_custom_endpoint = "${pdict.mycustom.customControllerPaths.endpointA}
</script>

<script src="${pdict.mycustom.scriptUrls.scriptOne}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<iscomment>
    Custom Head Content End
</iscomment>

I'm not sure this is the correct way to manage it but... it seems that the hook is not used, I've tried any type of page (contact, pdp, collection, home...)
simply app.template.htmlHead is not working.
I've tried with a really simple hook file instead of mine
// cartridge/scripts/hooks/app/template.js

'use strict';

var Logger = require('dw/system/Logger');

function htmlHead() {
    Logger.info('htmlHead hook is called');
    return '<!-- Test htmlHead hook -->';
}

exports.htmlHead = htmlHead;

but I get no comment and nothing in the logs... so, I suppose it is not related to my code.
How can I add the JS code to the HEAD without overriding any template??? it seems impossible that something so basic is so complex
I've also tried to add the hook definition to hooks.json but I do not think it is needed, it should be automatically used if the folder structure is correct.
So... what am I doing wrong? Where can I find info about this topic?
Thanks!

The issue was related to misplaced hooks file.
I created a package.json file INSIDE THE CARTRIDGE
like this
{
    "hooks": "./hooks.json"
}

and a hooks.json file in which I defined
{
    "hooks": [
        {
            "name": "app.template.htmlHead",
            "script": "./cartridge/scripts/hooks/app/template.js"
        }
    ]
}

it seems there is no sort of auto-discover mechanism based on path
